# How to draw Kiviat Diagrams

Tags: tkz-kiviat

> **This question led to a new package:**
>   [`tkz-kiviat`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tkz-kiviat)

Is there a way to draw [Kiviat diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiviat_diagram) easily?

[image: Sample Kiviat diagram]

Comment: these are both rich answers! thank you very much for your help

Comment: Welcome to {TeX}. I've converted your 'answer' to a comment. Usually, simple 'thanks' comments are not really encouraged, as we have a voting model for good-quality answers. You can upvote good answers, and as this is your question can also accept the 'best' one (use the tick by the answers to do this).

Comment: I've edited the question to add one of the pictures you linked to. Once you get enough reputation you'll be able to do this yourself: for the moment, you can add a comment to your questions asking someone to do this for you, where necessary.

Comment: Related Question: [Problem drawing Kiviat diagram](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10240/problem-drawing-kiviat-diagram).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It was interesting to make a package to use TikZ to build Kiviat Diagram. This package is now on CTAN:
[`tkz-kiviat`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tkz-kiviat).
You can find some examples on my homepage:
[kiviat examples](http://altermundus.com/pages/tkz/kiviat/index.html).

The first example uses three macros with arguments. First, you create a spider, then you can create a kiviat polygon and you can create graduations

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[upright]{fourier} 
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tkz-kiviat,numprint,fullpage} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzKiviatDiagram[scale=1.25,label distance=.5cm,
        radial  = 5,
        gap     = 1,  
        lattice = 5]{McCabe,LOC,Live Variables,Halstead N,Variablenspanne}
\tkzKiviatLine[thick,color=blue,mark=none,
               fill=blue!20,opacity=.5](3,3.5,3,3.5,3)
\tkzKiviatLine[thick,color=darkgray,
               fill=green!20,opacity=.5](0.5,1,0.5,0.75,1) 
\tkzKiviatLine[ultra thick,mark=ball,
                 mark size=4pt,color =Maroon](2,3.75,1,1.5,2)    
\tkzKiviatGrad[prefix=,unity=100,suffix=\ \texteuro](1)  
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: kiviat example]

Another solution is to use an external file with data

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[upright]{fourier}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tkz-kiviat,numprint,fullpage} 
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzKiviatDiagramFromFile[
        scale=.5,
        label distance=.5cm,
        gap     = 1,label space=3,  
        lattice = 10]{tableae.dat}
\tkzKiviatLineFromFile[thick,
                       color      = blue,
                       mark       = ball,
                       ball color = blue,
                       mark size  = 4pt,
                       fill       = blue!20]{tableae.dat}{2}
\tkzKiviatLineFromFile[thick,
                       color      = red,
                       mark       = ball,
                       ball color = red,
                       mark size  = 4pt,
                       fill       = red!20]{tableae.dat}{1} 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The tableae.dat file is used with the package pgfplotstable.sty

```
%tableae.dat
column1                    column2   column3 
Reliability                6           6.5
Usability                  4           9
{Application Architecture} 7           8
{Version Control}          6.5         7
Timeliness                 2           8
Efficiency                 3           4
Effectiveness              5           6.5
Interoperability           1.5         7
```

[image: kiviat diagram with an external file]

Comment: unfortunately I do get an ! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> 360/\tkz@kiv@radial *\rang 
                                      :\tkz@kiv@lattice *\tkz@kiv@gap +\tkz@...
l.15 ...Live Variables,Halstead N,Variablenspanne}
What am I missing here? Does it require cvs version of tikz? I'm going with Ubuntus packed version of pgf/tikz 2.0

Comment: @adnc I made it with pgf 2.1 This is the new version of pgf

Comment: @adnc  you can get pgf 2.1 here http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/  and you can install it in your texmf.

Comment: I again need to say that this solution is great!

Comment: @doncherry Yes I created this package for this question

Comment: Unforunately, the arrows seem to draw to the center of the text rather than edge. This is visible when you use longer text for the labels. For example, try `\begin{tikzpicture}\tkzKiviatDiagram[gap=.25,label space=.75]{Long text,Long text,Long text,Long text,Long text}\end{tikzpicture}`

Comment: It's also pretty visible in the example screenshots above. The labels on the vertical axis are further away from the arrow than the labels on the horizontal.

Comment: Just a comment to report a deadlink on your personal website

Comment: @AlainMatthes - how to add a legend for each coloured line? There's no note of this in the docs. Highly useful CTAN package btw, thanks.

Comment: @pdsI made this package 8 years ago and I have never seen the code since ... ! But no you can't add legend with it. You need to use TikZ to do the legend. I don't have enough time to help you because I have to finish another package quickly. Ask a question about this ... (Some examples of the documentation have some problem with pgf >3 )

Comment: @pds I finish tkz-euclide and I look to answer ...

Comment: Thanks for reply @AlainMatthes, I understand. This excerpt serves my purpose, but it's not responsive to label length variations. Please feel free to use/modify. `\renewcommand{\tkzKiviatLegend}[2]{\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[draw=black!05] (-0.1,-0.2) rectangle ++(6.25,0.5);
    \draw [thick, blue] (0,0) -- (1,0); 
    \node at (2.15,0) {#2};
    \draw [thick, green] (3.25,0) -- (4.25,0); 
    \node at (5.25,0) {#1};
\end{tikzpicture}}`

Comment: Your linked homepage seems to be down.

Comment: @dexteritas  yes altermundus.com is closed. I'll put some examples on http://altermundus.fr in a while but I have to update the package first. I don't have the time now.

Comment: @Alain Matthes: Sadly your package is out of TEXLive, I had to install it manually.

Comment: @ThomasBenko yes you are right and I'm sorry but I don't have time to do it and I'm currently only working on `tkz-euclide`. I haven't used it for more than 10 years and I don't even know if it is still compatible with the new versions of pgf.

Comment: @Alain Matthes: The compatibility is a little borderlined. (And as a math theacher, I'm happy to know, you are working on tkz-euclide, I use that pack very heavily.)

Answer (score 19):

I'd go fot the `tikz` package.

Have a look at [this](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/spiderweb-diagram/) example.

---

I've written a crude set of macro's that might help you on your way when making your own (adjust these and you should be fine).

I'm not that great a programmer myself so perhaps someone else will come up with something much more refined but this will do for now. The upside to my little programming skills is that the code is easy, so you'll probably be able to grasp it quickly and adjust it to your needs.

There are 4 macro's. The main macro is `\spider`, it takes as much parameters as there are axes (I've written the code for 8 axes, adjust it if you need more or less using the `\n` command and some tweaking in the code). Each paramter of `\spider` stands for a value on the the corresponding axis.

`\outertolerance` works the same way as spider and sets the outer tolerance band for the next `\spider`to take into account. The same way `\innertolerance` sets the values for the inner tolerance band.

Everytime a `\spider`is used the `\outertolerance`and `\innertolerance` values are reset to nothing (draw no tolerance bands). You can also reset them youerself this by hand using `\resettolerance`

Add this to preamble:

```
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\n{8}   %define how much axes you want
\def\N{5}   %define the number of node on each axis

\newcommand{\spider}[\n]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]

        \thebigtolerance

        \foreach \x in{0,1,...,\n}{%
            \draw[->] (0,0)--(360/\n*\x:\N+0.5);
            \foreach \y in{0,1,...,\N}{
                \draw[thin,lightgray](360/\n*\x:\y)--(360/\n*\x+360/\n:\y);
                \draw[fill] (360/\n*\x:\y) circle(0.75pt);
                }

        }

        \draw(360/\n:\N+0.5)node[right]{axis1};     %adjust the labels (also add or delete exces axes)
        \draw(2*360/\n:\N+0.5)node[above]{axis2};   %eg. if you have 6 axes, delete the last 2
        \draw(3*360/\n:\N+0.5)node[left]{axis3};        %or if you have 9 axes add one
        \draw(4*360/\n:\N+0.5)node[left]{axis4};
        \draw(5*360/\n:\N+0.5)node[left]{axis5};
        \draw(6*360/\n:\N+0.5)node[below]{axis6};
        \draw(7*360/\n:\N+0.5)node[right]{axis7};
        \draw(8*360/\n:\N+0.5)node[right]{axis8};

        \thesmalltolerance

        \draw[thick,draw=red](360/\n:#1)--(360/\n*2:#2)--(360/\n*3:#3)--(360/\n*4:#4)--(360/\n*5:#5)--(360/\n*6:#6)--(360/\n*7:#7)--(360/\n*8:#8)--cycle;
        %add or remove coordinates if you have more or less than 8 axes


    \end{tikzpicture}
    \resettolerance 
}


\newcommand{\thesmalltolerance}[0]{}
\newcommand{\innertolerance}[\n]{
    \renewcommand{\thesmalltolerance}{\draw[fill=gray,thick,opacity=0.3](360/\n:#1)--(360/\n*2:#2)--(360/\n*3:#3)--(360/\n*4:#4)--(360/\n*5:#5)--(360/\n*6:#6)--(360/\n*7:#7)--(360/\n*8:#8)--cycle;}
    %add or remove coordinates if you have more or less than 8 axes
}

\newcommand{\thebigtolerance}[0]{}
\newcommand{\outertolerance}[\n]{
    \renewcommand{\thebigtolerance}{
        \foreach \x in{1,2,...,\n}{
            \draw[draw=none,fill=gray,opacity=0.3](0,0)--(360/\n*\x:\N)--(360/\n*\x+360/\n:\N);}

        \draw[fill=white,thick,draw=gray](360/\n:#1)--(360/\n*2:#2)--(360/\n*3:#3)--(360/\n*4:#4)--(360/\n*5:#5)--(360/\n*6:#6)--(360/\n*7:#7)--(360/\n*8:#8)--cycle;
        %add or remove coordinates if you have more or less than 8 axes
    }
}

\newcommand{\resettolerance}[0]{%resets the tolerance band to none
    \renewcommand{\thebigtolerance}{}
    \renewcommand{\thesmalltolerance}{}
}
```

As said above, you will need to adjust the drawing commands to fit the number of axis. This means adding `(360/\n*9:#9)--` if you want nine axes. Or removing `(360/\n*8:#8)--` if you want 7 axes. You should do this in 3 places (in the `\spider`command, and in `\outertolerance` and `\innertolerance`. The adjustment should be the same for every command.

You can also adjust the number of nodes on each axis by adjusting the `\N` number. You might have to also adjust the `scaling=0.5` because more nodes means a bigger chart.

I've also made an example of how to actually draw the spider chart:

```
\outertolerance{4}{4}{4}{3}{4}{4}{4.5}{4}%defines the outer toleranceband for next spider
\innertolerance{1}{1}{1}{1}{1}{2}{2}{1}%defines the inner toleranceband for next spider
\spider{2}{2}{2}{2}{3}{4}{4}{3}%draws the spider diagram with coordinates
```

Hope this helps!

[image: example]

Comment: this is really good, except i would need to plot one dataset  and also a toleranceband

Comment: is this a one time deal or do you need a macro that will be used several times?

Comment: I'll need to produce these diagrams several times.

Comment: Play around with the `tikz` package. It provides great possibilities for drawing any diagrams. 

analyse the example I gave you and you'll come up with something.

Comment: I don't have enough time tonight but tomorrow, I can make a macro to draw these diagrams. Ineed only to know what to you want like options, variables. What is constant and i make this for you !

Answer (score 14):

With the current [pstricks-add.tex](http://texnik.dante.de/tex/generic/pstricks-add/) you can simplify it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\def\Tab#1{\tabular{@{}l@{}}#1\endtabular}
\begin{document}

\psframebox*[fillcolor=yellow!15]{%
\begin{pspicture}(-6,-5)(5,5)
\psset{unit=1.2}
\psKiviat[rotate=0.5,
          yLabels={Marketing,Sales,Administration,\Tab{Information\\Technology},%
           \Tab{Customer\\Support},Developer},
  labelsep=10pt]{6}{3}
\psKiviatTicklines[Dx=0.5,linecolor=black!30]{6}{3}
\psKiviatAxes[linecolor=black!30]{7}{3}
\psKiviatLine[linewidth=2pt,linecolor=blue!60]{1,2,1,1.7,1.3,3}
\psKiviatLine[linewidth=2pt,linecolor=red!60]{2.25,2.5,0.6,1.2,1,1}
\multido{\rA=0.5+0.5,\iA=10+10}{6}{\uput[3](0,\rA){\$\iA}}
\end{pspicture}}

\clearpage
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)
\psKiviat[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=red!20,
  yLabels={McCabe,LOC,Live Variables,Halstead N,Variablenspanne},
  labelsep=20pt]{5}{4}
\psKiviatLine[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white]{3,3.5,3,3.5,3}
\psKiviatLine[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=black!10]{0.5,1,0.5,0.75,1}
\psKiviatLine[dotstyle=square*,linewidth=1.5pt,linecolor=red]{2,3.75,1,1.5,2}
\psKiviatTicklines[Dx=0.5,subtickcolor=black!15]{5}{4}
\psKiviatAxes[arrows=->,arrowscale=2]{5}{4.5}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: thanks, on page 9 there is an example i'm looking for. the values wouldnt matter. http://books.google.com/books?id=mUTtO9HhTX0C&pg=PA9&lpg=PA9&dq=kiviat+diagramm+metrik&source=bl&ots=JjkfmaxNEU&sig=-rzrZEkvZxGRkQbt3CgtvVV-j7s&hl=de&ei=O45ITf-CD8nCswauhKGMAw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=kiviat%20diagramm%20metrik&f=false

Comment: @adnc: I added an example. Run it with `xetex` or load package `auto-pst-pdf` and run it with `pdflatex -shell-escape file`

Comment: Unfortunately I can't get it compile. It hangs on a "Undefined control sequence" `! Undefined control sequence.
\resetOptions ...\pst@linetype {0}\pstScalePoints 
                                                  (1,1){}{}\psset [pstricks-...
l.2277 \resetOptions
`

Comment: @adnc: what TeX distribution do you have installed and what operatinf system are you running?

Comment: @herbert I'm running Ubuntu 10.10 and TeX Live

Comment: @adnc: ok, if it is the TeX Live from Ubuntu it is really out of date. Go to `http://texnik.dante.de`, there is a link for a complete tarzip of all pstricks files. They are always in the correct directories, which should also on ubuntu at `???/texlive-texmf/` or something else. After running `texhash` your pstricks system is up to date.

Comment: @herbert I'm facing this problem now ! Undefined control sequence.
\psKiviat@i ...e \def \pst@Coordinates {} \psLoop 
                                                  {#1}{\xdef \pst@Coordinate...
l.12   labelsep=20pt]{5}{4} although \psKiviat is available in the pstricks-add.tex

Comment: @adnc: yes, but you didn't have the newest `pstricks.tex`. It defines the `\psLoop` macro

Comment: @herbert I downloaded http://archiv.dante.de/~herbert/PSTricks-TDS.tgz and installed it as you suggested. But \psLoop is not defined inside. So where can I take it from?

Comment: @adnc: maybe that I did sonwething wrong, but this version `http://texnik.dante.de/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex` has it. Put also `\listfiles` as first line into the document, then you'll get a list of all loaded files at the end of the log file.

Comment: @herbert, yes thats it! Great work, thank you very much.

Comment: @adnc: when you want to rotate the diagram use `rotate=<angle>`. But you have to remember that the whole circle has 6 degrees in the first and 5 degrees in the second example. The reason why I used `rotate=0.5` in the first example, which is the same as 30 degrees for a 360° circle