# Converting numbers to scientific notations

Tags: math-mode, macros

I have some numbers output from Matlab and I want to show them as tables in LaTeX. The numbers are in the form `0.14190949656253118000` or `0.01234e-3` and I want to show them in scientific notation. How can I find/write, a macro that is called like `\scn{0.14190949656253118000}`  or `\scn{0.01234e-3}` and results in `$1.41x10^{-1}$` or `$1.23x10^{-5}$`. Note that the number of digits after the decimal points should be configable.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Working from Boris' answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[scientific-notation=true]{siunitx}
\listfiles
\begin{document}

%\num{0.14190949656253118000}
\num{0.1419094965}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, for your particular number, siunitx versions lower than 2.4n return a "number too big" error unless you round the number off (as you had originally indicated, but I forgot about). That prompted me to write the following MATLAB function that will print the LaTeX code for your numbers to whatever precision you want:

```
function s=pp(x,n)
% pretty-print a value in scientific notation
% usage: s=pp(x,n)
% where: x a floating-point value
%        n is the number of decimal places desired
%        s is the string representation of x with n decimal places, and
%          exponent k
exponent=floor(log10(abs(x))); %to accomodate for negative values
mantissa=x/(10^exponent);
s=sprintf('$%*.*f \\times 10^{%d}$',n+3,n,mantissa,exponent);
% returns something like '$1.42 \times 10^{-1}$'
```

Examples:

```
>> s1=pp(0.14190949656253118000,2)
s1 =
$1.42 \times 10^{-1}$
>> s2=pp(0.01234e-3,3)
s2 =
$1.234 \times 10^{-5}$
```

But again, any recent version of siunitx and Boris' answer will work fine for rounded numbers, and siunitx 2.4n will work fine even without rounding.

Comment: Which version of `siunitx` do you have? You should not get the 'too big' error with the latest release.

Comment: I'll update and check again.

Comment: Updated from CTAN, got siunitx 2.4l, same problem. Updating answer with new details.

Comment: Ah, that's not quite what I tried :-) The question indicates that the output should be rounded (which was where there used to be a bug with the number of digits in the mantissa!). So I both rounded and forced scientific notation, which works fine. I will investigate this other issue when I get a moment.

Comment: Yep. Forgot the rounding, which Boris remembered to include.

Comment: Fixed in v2.4n, sent to CTAN a moment ago (I hope!).

Answer (score 20):

The macro `\num` from, e.g. [siunitx](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) does just this.  For example

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\num[round-precision=2,round-mode=figures]{0.1419094};
\num[round-precision=2,round-mode=figures,
     scientific-notation=true]{0.1419094};
\num[round-precision=2,round-mode=figures,
     scientific-notation=true]{0.1419094e-6};
\num[round-precision=2,round-mode=figures,
     scientific-notation=engineering]{0.1419094e-6}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that too many digits in the input may lead to error "Number is too big".

Also, the optional arguments in `\num` can be set for all numbers using `\sisetup`.

Comment: It would be better to show a complete example. By default `\num{0.14190949656253118000}` produces `0.141 909 496 562 531 180 00}`

Comment: ok, added some examples

Comment: Thanks Boris, I just defined a macro like this `\newcommand{\sn}[1]{\num[round-precision=2,round-mode=figures,scientific-notation=true]{#1}}` since I want to make the numbers consistent throughout the document.

Comment: easier to say `\sisetup{round-precision=2,round-mode=figures,scientific-notation=true}`, and then just user `\num`.