# Rounding integers in table with siunitx

Tags: tables, siunitx

My problem is to round numbers that are integers so, for example, I have 123456789 but I only want to have 123 * 10^6 in the table cell.

example code:

```
\begin{table}
\caption{Table} \label{tab:tab}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l S}
\hline
 Name & {number} \\
\hline
 a & 18799382 \\
 b & 16492855 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

I want to round the second column to have an output of something like:

```
\begin{table}
\caption{Table} \label{tab:tab}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l S}
\hline
 Name & {number} \\
\hline
 a & 188e5 \\
 b & 165e5 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Is [Converting numbers to scientific notations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50659/124842) helpful or are you looking for an automatic solution?

Comment: Actually, that is useful, I just didn't know that the same controls work for tabular, but now it is obvious as I see the solution of @JosephWright.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to do two things:

- Turn on rounding with appropriate settings
- Turn on fixed exponents with appropriate settings

Thus something like

```
\begin{tabular}
{
  l
  S[round-mode = figures,
   round-precision = 3,
   scientific-notation = fixed,
   fixed-exponent = 5]
}
```