# Filter table rows for regression

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I have a table containing a flag and x and y values. I'd like to have a regression for all rows with 1 in the first column. How can I do this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5.1}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
  \pgfplotstableread{
    Exmpl  a   v
    1      0   0
    1      1   1
    1      2   1
    1      3   4
    2      0   -0
    2      1   -1
    2      2   -1
    2      3   -4
  } \data
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis} % [legend pos=outer north east]
      \addplot table [x=a, y=v] {\data};
      \addplot table [x=a, y={create col/linear regression={y=v}}] {\data};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I think, the pgfplots filters don't apply here, since I guess, pgfplots only gets the x and y values. It would be great, if there is a possibility to create a filtered table and do the regression and plotting stuff from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I have almost the solution with the help of two questions:
[Create a contingency table using pgfplotstable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62409/create-a-contingency-table-using-pgfplotstable) and
[Accessing individual table elements with pgfplots?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12962/accessing-individual-table-elements-with-pgfplots)
The idea is, to transpose the matrix, create a new matrix, loop over all columns and copy the columns, if the Exmpl - value is 1.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5.1}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand{\pgfplotstablefilterrows}[3]
{
  \pgfplotstablegetrowsof{#1}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\NumOfRows}{\pgfplotsretval}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\MaxRow}{\NumOfRows-1}
  \pgfplotstablegetcolsof{#1}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\NumOfCols}{\pgfplotsretval}

  \pgfplotstabletranspose{\TransposedData}{#1}
  \pgfplotstableset{create on use/TransposedHead/.style={copy column from table={\TransposedData}{[index]0}}}
  \pgfplotstablenew[columns={TransposedHead}]{\NumOfCols}{\TransposedFilteredData}
  \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \pgfplotstablerowindex in {0,1,...,\MaxRow}{ % Row loop
    #3
  }
  \pgfplotstabletranspose[colnames from=TransposedHead,input colnames to=]{#2}{\TransposedFilteredData}
  \pgfplotstableclear{\TransposedData}
  \pgfplotstableclear{\TransposedFilteredData}
}

\begin{document}
  \pgfplotstableread{
    Exmpl  a   v
    1      0   0
    1      1   1
    1      2   1
    1      3   4
    2      0   -0
    2      1   -1
    2      2   -1
    2      3   -4
  } \data

  \pgfplotstablefilterrows{\data}{\FilteredData}
  {
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfplotstablerowindex}{[index]0}\of\data
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\pgfplotsretval}{1}}
    {
      \pgfplotstablecreatecol[copy column from table={\TransposedData}{\pgfplotstablerowindex}]{\pgfplotstablerowindex}{\TransposedFilteredData}
    }
    {}
  }

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis} % [legend pos=outer north east]
      \addplot table [x=a, y=v] {\data};
      \addplot table [x=a, y={create col/linear regression={y=v}}] {\FilteredData}; % compute a linear regression from the input table
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As you might see from the code, I'm not really experienced in latex programming.
Anyway, it works.
Best,
    Juhui

Comment: This is great and helpful. However, the macro *\pgfplotstablefilterrows* cannot be called a second time as \pgfplotstablelistfront complains about an EMPTY list. Do you know why?