# pgfplots: empty list error

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I am trying to filter some data before plotting it and showing a
regression line.  I am basing my approach on
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69173/110494 . I want to filter the
same data file in different ways.  The mock-up below filters based on
the value of column c.  It plots the data how I want, but as soon as I
uncomment the commented out code in the preamble in preparation to
draw a second plot (also commented out) I get this error:

> ! Package pgfplots Error: \pgfplotslistfront\ from
>   \pgfplotstable@colnames\ although list is EMPTY.

Can anyone explain this, or provide a solution?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable,ifthen}
\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
a, b, c, d, e
0, 1, 1, 8, 13
0, 1, 1, 4, 15
0, 1, 1, 4, 14
0, 1, 1, 5, 12
0, 1, 1, 6, 15
0, 1, 1, 7, 14
0, 1, 2, 10, 21
0, 1, 2, 12, 23
0, 1, 2, 14, 25
0, 1, 2, 16, 28
\end{filecontents}
\newcommand{\pgfplotstablefilterrows}[3]
{ \pgfplotstablegetrowsof{#1}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\NumOfRows}{\pgfplotsretval}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\MaxRow}{\NumOfRows-1}
  \pgfplotstablegetcolsof{#1}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\NumOfCols}{\pgfplotsretval}
  \pgfplotstabletranspose{\TransposedData}{#1}
  \pgfplotstableset{create on use/TransposedHead/.style={copy column from table={\TransposedData}{[index]0}}}
  \pgfplotstablenew[columns={TransposedHead}]{\NumOfCols}{\TransposedFilteredData}
  \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \pgfplotstablerowindex in {0,1,...,\MaxRow}{ % Row loop
    #3
  }
  \pgfplotstabletranspose[colnames from=TransposedHead,input colnames to=]{#2}{\TransposedFilteredData}
  \pgfplotstableclear{\TransposedData}
  \pgfplotstableclear{\TransposedFilteredData}
}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data.csv}{\dataone}
\pgfplotstablefilterrows{\dataone}{\FilteredDataOne}
  {\pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfplotstablerowindex}{[index]2}\of\dataone\ifthenelse{\equal{\pgfplotsretval}{1}}
  {\pgfplotstablecreatecol[copy column from table={\TransposedData}{\pgfplotstablerowindex}]{\pgfplotstablerowindex}{\TransposedFilteredData}}
  {}
}
% uncommenting this gives an error
% \pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data.csv}{\datatwo}
% \pgfplotstablefilterrows{\datatwo}{\FilteredDataTwo}
%   {\pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfplotstablerowindex}{[index]2}\of\datatwo\ifthenelse{\equal{\pgfplotsretval}{2}}
%   {\pgfplotstablecreatecol[copy column from table={\TransposedData}{\pgfplotstablerowindex}]{\pgfplotstablerowindex}{\TransposedFilteredData}}
%   {}
% }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[unbounded coords=jump]
    \addplot [only marks] table [x=d, y=e] {\FilteredDataOne};
    \addplot [smooth,no marks, thick, red] table [x=d, y={create col/linear regression={y=e}}] {\FilteredDataOne};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
% \begin{tikzpicture}
%   \begin{axis}[unbounded coords=jump]
%     \addplot [only marks] table [x=d, y=e] {\FilteredDataTwo};
%     \addplot [smooth,no marks, thick, red] table [x=d, y={create col/linear regression={y=e}}] {\FilteredDataTwo};
%   \end{axis}
% \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't say why, but it works if you do *not* clear the two transposed tables, i.e. comment out/remove

```
\pgfplotstableclear{\TransposedData}
\pgfplotstableclear{\TransposedFilteredData}
```

from the definition of `\pgfplotstablefilterrows`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,ifthen}
\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
a, b, c, d, e
0, 1, 1, 8, 13
0, 1, 1, 4, 15
0, 1, 1, 4, 14
0, 1, 1, 5, 12
0, 1, 1, 6, 15
0, 1, 1, 7, 14
0, 1, 2, 10, 21
0, 1, 2, 12, 23
0, 1, 2, 14, 25
0, 1, 2, 16, 28
\end{filecontents}
\newcommand{\pgfplotstablefilterrows}[3]
{ \pgfplotstablegetrowsof{#1}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\NumOfRows}{\pgfplotsretval}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\MaxRow}{\NumOfRows-1}
  \pgfplotstablegetcolsof{#1}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\NumOfCols}{\pgfplotsretval}
  \pgfplotstabletranspose{\TransposedData}{#1}
  \pgfplotstableset{create on use/TransposedHead/.style={copy column from table={\TransposedData}{[index]0}}}
  \pgfplotstablenew[columns={TransposedHead}]{\NumOfCols}{\TransposedFilteredData}
  \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \pgfplotstablerowindex in {0,1,...,\MaxRow}{ % Row loop
    #3
  }
  \pgfplotstabletranspose[colnames from=TransposedHead,input colnames to=]{#2}{\TransposedFilteredData}
%  \pgfplotstableclear{\TransposedData}
%  \pgfplotstableclear{\TransposedFilteredData}
}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data.csv}{\dataone}
\pgfplotstablefilterrows{\dataone}{\FilteredDataOne}
{
  \pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfplotstablerowindex}{[index]2}\of\dataone
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\pgfplotsretval}{1}}
     {\pgfplotstablecreatecol[copy column from table={\TransposedData}{\pgfplotstablerowindex}]{\pgfplotstablerowindex}{\TransposedFilteredData}}
     {}
}

% uncommenting this gives an error
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data.csv}{\datatwo}
\pgfplotstablefilterrows{\datatwo}{\FilteredDataTwo}
{
  \pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfplotstablerowindex}{[index]2}\of\datatwo
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\pgfplotsretval}{2}}
     {\pgfplotstablecreatecol[copy column from table={\TransposedData}{\pgfplotstablerowindex}]{\pgfplotstablerowindex}{\TransposedFilteredData}}
     {}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[unbounded coords=jump]
    \addplot [only marks] table [x=d, y=e] {\FilteredDataOne};
    \addplot [smooth,no marks, thick, red] table [x=d, y={create col/linear regression={y=e}}] {\FilteredDataOne};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[unbounded coords=jump]
     \addplot [only marks] table [x=d, y=e] {\FilteredDataTwo};
     \addplot [smooth,no marks, thick, red] table [x=d, y={create col/linear regression={y=e}}] {\FilteredDataTwo};
   \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```