# tkz-kiviat : increase label length and get the right legend

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-kiviat

I want to draw a spider/kiviat diagram. I am using the `tkz-kiviat` library but I have some problems. Here is my MWE

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames}]{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[upright]{fourier}
\usepackage{tkz-kiviat,numprint} 

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing, arrows, fit}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{xmpmulti}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}


%\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=red!80!black}
%\setbeamertemplate{items}[circle]


\newcommand{\LegendBox}[3][]{%
\xdef\fitbox{}%
\coordinate[#1] (LegendBox_anchor) at (#2) ;
    \foreach \col/\item [count=\hi from 0] in {#3} {
       \node[color = \col,draw,
             fill  = \col!50,
             minimum width  = 4 ex,
             minimum height = 2 ex,
             label={[anchor = left,name=b\hi]right :\item}] at ([yshift=\hi*4 ex]LegendBox_anchor) {};
             \xdef\fitbox{\fitbox(b\hi)}
   }%
 \node [draw,fit=\fitbox(LegendBox_anchor)] {};
}

\title{MWE}
\date{\today}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{adjustbox}{max totalsize={.9\textwidth}{.8\textheight},center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[label distance=.15cm]
\begin{scope}
 \tkzKiviatDiagram[
        radial=5,
        radial  style/.style ={-},
        lattice style/.style ={blue!30}]
      {\LARGE Exhaustivité, \LARGE Descripteurs sociologiques, \LARGE Données conditions de vie, \LARGE Richesse des informations sur le revenu, \LARGE Coût}
 \tkzKiviatLine[thick,color=red,mark=ball,
                ball color=red,mark size=4pt,fill=red!20](5,9,6,8,4)
 \tkzKiviatLine[thick,color=blue,mark=ball,
                mark size=4pt,fill=blue!20,opacity=.5](9,6,8,4,5) 
 \tkzKiviatLine[thick,color=green,mark=ball, ball color=green,
                mark size=4pt,fill=green!20,opacity=.5](3,8,8,6,8)                 
                \end{scope}
\LegendBox[shift={(3cm,3.5cm)}]{current bounding box.south east}%
          {red/ ERFS,
           blue/ FiLoSoFi,
           green/ SRCV }                
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{frame}  
\end{document}
```

And what I get is 
[image]

I have several things I would like to change :

- My legend is obviously wrong, I think it is something in the label of the `\LegendBox` new command, but I have not found what.
  I took the code from an answer to [Spider Graph Legend and Caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107232/spider-graph-legend-and-caption).
- I would like the labels of my axes to be larger, that is to have my text less cut
- Last, I would like to have less lines on my diagram (each of the ten units is drawn, I would like only the even ones)

Thanks

Comment: It could be more minimal ;). It works better (but not correctly) if you comment the call to `babel`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some modifications.

1. I redefined the `\LegendBox` command to produce a proper result.
2. You can use the style `label style` to specify a bigger `text width` for the labels.
3. This requires a redefinition of `\tkz@KiviatDiagram` so the loop drawing the lines has two as step instead of one. (You should consider asking the package creatot to add an option allowing to control the stepping for the lattice). I also did some other adjustments so the anchor for the nodes containing the labels can be changed.

The code:

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames}]{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[upright]{fourier}
\usepackage{tkz-kiviat,numprint} 

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing, arrows, fit}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{xmpmulti}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}


%\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=red!80!black}
%\setbeamertemplate{items}[circle]


\newcommand{\LegendBox}[3][]{%
\xdef\fitbox{}%
\coordinate[#1] (LegendBox_anchor) at (#2) ;
    \foreach \col/\item [count=\hi from 0] in {#3} {
       \node[color = \col,draw,
             fill  = \col!10,
             minimum width  = 5 ex,
             minimum height = 2 ex,
             name=b\hi,
       ] at ([yshift=\hi*4 ex,xshift=3ex]LegendBox_anchor) {};
       \node[anchor=west,xshift=1ex] at (b\hi.east) (c\hi) {\item};
       \xdef\fitbox{\fitbox(c\hi)}
   }%
 \node [draw,fit=\fitbox(LegendBox_anchor)] {};
}

\makeatletter
\def\tkz@KiviatDiagram[#1]#2{% 

\pgfkeys{/kiviat/.cd,
gap          = .5,
lattice      = 10,
space        = .5,
step         = 1,
label space  = 1.5
}
\pgfqkeys{/kiviat}{#1}%
\begingroup
\foreach \x [count=\rang from 1] in {#2}{%
\global\let\tkz@kiv@radial\rang}% 
\foreach \x [count=\rang from 0] in {#2}{%
   \draw[/kiviat/radial style]
 (0,0)--(360/\tkz@kiv@radial*\rang:\tkz@kiv@lattice*\tkz@kiv@gap+\tkz@kiv@sp);
   \path
(0,0)--(360/\tkz@kiv@radial*\rang:\tkz@kiv@lattice*\tkz@kiv@gap+\tkz@kiv@space) node[anchor={180+360/\tkz@kiv@radial*\rang},/kiviat/label style] {\x}; 

\foreach \y in {0,2,...,\tkz@kiv@lattice}{
   \draw[/kiviat/lattice style]%
     (360/\tkz@kiv@radial*\rang:\y*\tkz@kiv@gap)--%
        (360/\tkz@kiv@radial*\rang+360/\tkz@kiv@radial:\y*\tkz@kiv@gap);
     }
}
\endgroup
}
\makeatother

\title{MWE}
\date{\today}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{adjustbox}{max totalsize={.9\textwidth}{.8\textheight},center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
 \tkzKiviatDiagram[
        radial=5,
        label style/.append style={font=\Huge,text width=6cm,align=left,shift={(-5pt,0pt)}},
        radial  style/.style ={-},
        lattice style/.style ={blue!30},
        ]
      {Exhaustivité, Descripteurs sociologiques, Données conditions de vie, Richesse des informations sur le revenu, {\hfill Coût\hfill\null}}
 \tkzKiviatLine[thick,color=red,mark=ball,
                ball color=red,mark size=4pt,fill=red!20](5,9,6,8,4)
 \tkzKiviatLine[thick,color=blue,mark=ball,
                mark size=4pt,fill=blue!20,opacity=.5](9,6,8,4,5) 
 \tkzKiviatLine[thick,color=green,mark=ball, ball color=green,
                mark size=4pt,fill=green!20,opacity=.5](3,8,8,6,8)                 
                \end{scope}
\LegendBox[shift={(-2cm,3.5cm)}]{current bounding box.south east}%
          {red/ ERFS,
           blue/ FiLoSoFi,
           green/ SRCV }                
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{frame}  

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

## Remarks

- Since you are loading `babel` with `frenchb` option it's a good idea to load the `babel` library:

  ```
  \usetikzlibrary{babel}
  ```
- There's no need to load `amsmath` nor `graphicx` with `beamer` since the class internally loads them.

Comment: In fact it is almost perfect ! Do you know why the label "Exhaustivité" is the only one that collides with the figure ?

Comment: @Aerandal Yes, I know why and I provided a workaround. Notice that I introduced some changes both in the redefinitions and also in the document itself; in particualr, now th labels are introduced using `{Exhaustivité, Descripteurs sociologiques, Données conditions de vie, Richesse des informations sur le revenu, {\hfill Coût\hfill\null}}` the `\hfill`s are required because the label is too short fro the `6cm` declared as the text width.

Answer (score 1):

This only addresses the question about the legend but, since it is different from [Gonzalo Medina's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/257124/), it might be of interest. Rather than creating an additional node, I just named the existing one and added that to the list of things to be fitted.

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames},frenchb]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[upright]{fourier}
\usepackage{tkz-kiviat,numprint}

\usetikzlibrary{babel, fit}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\newcommand{\LegendBox}[3][]{%
  \xdef\fitbox{}%
  \coordinate[#1] (LegendBox_anchor) at (#2) ;
  \foreach \col/\item [count=\hi from 0] in {red/ ERFS,
    blue/ FiLoSoFi,
    green/ SRCV} {
    \node (d\hi) [
    color = \col,draw,
    fill  = \col!50,
    minimum width  = 4 ex,
    minimum height = 2 ex,
    label={[anchor = left, name=b\hi]right:\item}
    ] at ([yshift=\hi*4 ex]LegendBox_anchor) {};
    \xdef\fitbox{\fitbox (b\hi) (d\hi)}
  }%
  \node [draw, fit=\fitbox (LegendBox_anchor)] {};
}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{adjustbox}{max totalsize={.9\textwidth}{.8\textheight},center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[label distance=.15cm]
      \begin{scope}
        \tkzKiviatDiagram[
        radial  style/.style ={-},
        lattice style/.style ={blue!30}]
        {\LARGE Exhaustivité, \LARGE Descripteurs sociologiques, \LARGE Données conditions de vie, \LARGE Richesse des informations sur le revenu, \LARGE Coût}
        \tkzKiviatLine[thick,color=red,mark=ball,
        ball color=red,mark size=4pt,fill=red!20](5,9,6,8,4)
        \tkzKiviatLine[thick,color=blue,mark=ball,
        mark size=4pt,fill=blue!20,opacity=.5](9,6,8,4,5)
        \tkzKiviatLine[thick,color=green,mark=ball, ball color=green,
        mark size=4pt,fill=green!20,opacity=.5](3,8,8,6,8)
      \end{scope}
      \LegendBox[shift={(3cm,3.5cm)}]{current bounding box.south east}%
      {red/ ERFS,
        blue/ FiLoSoFi,
        green/ SRCV }
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{adjustbox}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: modified legend]