# How to handle more than 9 parameters in Kiviat Diagrams?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, parameters, charts

This email is regarding [Solution 2 mentioned in this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10060/how-to-draw-kiviat-diagrams) to draw Kiviat Diagrams.

This Solution is working perfectly upto 9 axis. But when we make number of axis as 10, it's giving error as : "You already have nine parameters."

Can you please suggest, how to handle more than 9 axis using second solution suggested in above mentioned URL.

Comment: The ordering of the answers isn't static on this site: they can be ordered by votes, or by time of posting, or by the time of the last edit. Do you mean romeov's answer?

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out; Yes it's  romeovs's answer.

Comment: That happens because you can not have a command with more than 9 parameters. See [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2132/how-to-make-define-a-command-that-takes-more-than-9-arguments) and modify the code