# LaTeX macro for OECD's "Magic Diamond"?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

Is there a LaTeX macro that can reproduce the [OECD's "Magic Diamond"](https://www.elibrary.imf.org/view/IMF071/01965-9781557750259/01965-9781557750259/ch01.xml) that is an indication of a country's economic performance?

Here's the "Magic Diamond" overview:

[image]

And here's what a specific "Magic Diamond" might look like showing a "before and after" or a "now and then" or "country A and country B" with two diamonds on the same axes (axes not labeled nor scaled with the economic indicators here - legend is missing too).

[image]

Ideally the macro would accept the four economic indicator numbers, or a sequence of sets of them, axis limits for each indicator, and then produce the diagram as shown in the images above or like this one below.

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But surely you will need to specify more than just the four values since the axis scales are different for each of them.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat  Yes, I updated the question to include the axis limits for each indicator.

Comment: @rickhg12hs I presume you want to input real data to be able to update your graph. If so, would you have a set of data that could be used in your MWE ?

Comment: @JeT I would be drawing data from one or more of the many economic statistics websites.  The quad diagram above seems to have axes limits of [1,5, 3.5] for GDP, [2, 12] for UNR (note the inverted scale), [-1, 5] for PCP (also inverted scale), and [-150, 100] for CB (inverted scale).  Note that it would be convenient to assign each economic indicator to any semi-axis and specify the precise text.  An example from the "Total OECD" for June 1986 looks to be about [GDP, UNR, PCP, CB] = [3.1, 8.2, 3.2, 7].

Comment: Is it a sort of [radar chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radar_chart) with four values and four specific scales ?

Comment: @PaulGaborit Yes, I think it is.

Comment: Then you might be interested in the [tkz-kiviat package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tkz-kiviat), which originated from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10060).

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat @PaulGaborit I don't see how to have independent axis scales with package `tkz-kiviat`.

Comment: Yes, I agree that this does not seem to be supported. The comment above was just to link to these plots, which seem to be very much like radar plots.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the question is yes, this can be done. Here is a prototype example. It sets up for different coordinate systems with their individual scalings, and plots the coordinates in those.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\tikzset{pics/Magic Diamond/.style={code={
    \tikzset{Magic Diamond/.cd,#1}%
    \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/Magic Diamond/##1}}% 
    \draw (-\pv{size}/2,-\pv{size}/2) rectangle (\pv{size}/2,\pv{size}/2);
    \foreach \XX [count=\YY] in {A,B,C,D}
    {\begin{scope}[shift={(-\YY*90:\pv{size}/2)},rotate={-90-\YY*90}]
     \pgfmathsetmacro{\first}{\pv{\XX min}}
     \pgfmathsetmacro{\next}{\first+\pv{\XX step}}
     \pgfmathifisint{\next}{\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\next}{\next}}{}
     \pgfmathsetmacro{\last}{\pv{\XX max}}
     \foreach \ZZ in {\first,\next,...,\last}
     {\draw ({(\ZZ-\first)*\pv{size}/(2*(\last-\first))},0) 
     node[anchor=180-\YY*90,node contents/.expanded=\ZZ] --     
      ++ (0,-\pv{tick length});}
     \draw[-stealth] (0,1) -- node[midway,anchor=180-\YY*90,
        node contents/.expanded=\pv{\XX}]{} (\pv{size}/2,1); 
    \end{scope}}
    \edef\lstABCD{"X","A","B","C","D"}
    \edef\DataSets{\pv{data}}
    \foreach \DataSet [count=\nData] in \DataSets
    {%\typeout{\DataSet}
     \foreach \DataPoint [count=\nDataPoint] in \DataSet
     {
     \pgfmathsetmacro{\currid}{{\lstABCD}[\nDataPoint]}
     \pgfmathsetmacro{\xtransformed}{(\DataPoint-\pv{\currid min})*%
        \pv{size}/(2*(\pv{\currid max}-\pv{\currid min}))}
     %\typeout{\nDataPoint,\DataPoint,\xtransformed}
     \path (-90-90*\nDataPoint:\xtransformed pt) coordinate (tmp-\nDataPoint);  
     }
     \pgfmathsetmacro{\mystyle}{{\pv{styles}}[\nData-1]}
     \draw[style/.expanded=\mystyle]  (tmp-1) -- (tmp-2) -- (tmp-3) -- (tmp-4) -- cycle;
    }
    }},Magic Diamond/.cd,size/.initial=10cm,tick length/.initial=3pt,
        Amax/.initial=5,Amin/.initial=0,Astep/.initial=1,A/.initial=CB,
        Bmax/.initial=5,Bmin/.initial=0,Bstep/.initial=1,B/.initial=PCB,
        Cmax/.initial=5,Cmin/.initial=0,Cstep/.initial=1,C/.initial=UNR,
        Dmax/.initial=5,Dmin/.initial=0,Dstep/.initial=1,D/.initial=GDP,
        data/.initial={{1,2,3,4},{1.5,2.5,1.5,2.5}},
        styles/.initial={"solid","dashed","red","orange","blue"}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \pic{Magic Diamond};   
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  I was hoping a package/macro already existed and I just couldn't find it.  I will indeed examine your prototype.

Comment: @rickhg12hs There are ternary diagrams, which are described in section **5.13 Ternary Diagrams** of the pgfplots manual v1.17. They come close conceptually but are AFAIK limited to 3 directions. I would not at all be surprised if something like the above existed in some form somewhere, but I am not aware of any post of that sort.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat This answer might become a classic for economists.

Comment: @JeT I think the second one may be more versatile. (I just fixed a really stupid bug there... )

Answer (score 2):

I usually do not add two answers, but this is a very different strategy than the other one. It uses `groupplots`, and is based on `pgfplots`, so highly customizable. All you need to do is to specify the data in a table such as

```
CB PCB UNR GDP
1 2 3 4
1.5 2.5 1.5 2.5
2 3 2.5 3.5
4 3 2 1
```

and the code will do the rest such as extracting the column names, finding the ranges, and producing the plots.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\pgfplotsset{% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75811/121799
    name nodes near coords/.style={nodes near coords={},
        every node near coord/.append style={anchor=center,coordinate,
            name=#1-\coordindex,
            alias=#1-last,
        },
    },
    name nodes near coords/.default=coordnode
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotstableread{
CB PCB UNR GDP
1 2 3 4
1.5 2.5 1.5 2.5
2 3 2.5 3.5
4 3 2 1
}{\loadedtable}
\edef\mystyles{"solid","dashed","red","orange","blue"}
\pgfplotstableforeachcolumn\loadedtable\as\col{%
\ifcase\pgfplotstablecol
\edef\mycolA{\col}%
\or
\edef\mycolB{\col}%
\or
\edef\mycolC{\col}%
\or
\edef\mycolD{\col}%
\or
\fi}
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\loadedtable}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\numrows}{\pgfplotsretval-1}%
\begin{groupplot}[
    group style={group name=top,group size=2 by 2,
        horizontal sep=0pt,vertical sep=0pt},height=4cm,width=4cm] 
\nextgroupplot[xtick=\empty,yticklabel pos=lower,ylabel=\mycolA,
    enlarge y limits=0.3,xmin=-1,xmax=0]
\addplot[only marks,name nodes near coords=\mycolA] 
    table[y expr=\thisrow{\mycolA},x expr=0]  {\loadedtable}; 
\nextgroupplot[ytick=\empty,xticklabel pos=upper,xlabel=\mycolB,
    enlarge x limits=0.3,ymax=1,ymin=0]
\addplot[only marks,name nodes near coords=\mycolB] 
    table[x expr=\thisrow{\mycolB},y expr=0]  {\loadedtable}; 
\nextgroupplot[ytick=\empty,xticklabel pos=lower,xlabel=\mycolC,
    enlarge x limits=0.3,ymax=0,ymin=-1,
    xticklabel={\pgfmathparse{-1*\tick}\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult}]
\addplot[only marks,name nodes near coords=\mycolC] 
    table[x expr=-1*\thisrow{\mycolC},y expr=0]  {\loadedtable}; 
\nextgroupplot[xtick=\empty,yticklabel pos=upper,ylabel=\mycolD,
    enlarge y limits=0.3,xmin=0,xmax=1,
    yticklabel={\pgfmathparse{-1*\tick}\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult}]
\addplot[only marks,name nodes near coords=\mycolD] 
    table[y expr=-1*\thisrow{\mycolD},x expr=0]  {\loadedtable}; 
\end{groupplot}
\foreach \X in {0,...,\numrows}
{\pgfmathsetmacro{\mystyle}{{\mystyles}[\X]}
\draw[style/.expanded=\mystyle] 
    (\mycolA-\X) -- (\mycolB-\X) -- (\mycolD-\X) -- (\mycolC-\X) -- cycle;}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**: Fixed an error in the tick labels of the axes pointing to the left or down.

Comment: Interesting!  I'll study this prototype too!

Comment: @rickhg12hs fully flexible answer by schodinger's. You can use `filecontents` package to save in a `.txt`, `.csv`, `.dat`, `.whatever`... the set of data you use. Very easy you'll see. http://ctan.tetaneutral.net/macros/latex/contrib/filecontents/filecontents.pdf